# Filter form for URI string parameters

Tags: php, codeigniter

For a filtered list web page, I want pass filters in the URI string. I.e.:

```
index.php/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male
```

According to CodeIgniter documentation it will be easy to retrieve the information using the URI Class. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html?highlight=uri%20class

My doubt:

In the view, How should I set up the filter form so that it calls a uri string based url (*index.php/user/search/name/joe/location/UK/gender/male*) instead of a regular POST (or GET) request?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing it like that you can structure your query like this,

`index.php/user/search?name=joe&location=UK&gender=male`

This way you can access the url parameters using `$data = $this->input->get()` and then access individual items like `$data['name'], $data['location'] and $data['gender']`.
And it would be also easier to set up the form with `get` method.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Sayantan Das. I know I can use a regular query string to transfer  form values. But my goal is to find out if is possible (and not absurdly complex) to transfer form values in the uri string.

Comment: in that case you can access the parameters by using `$this->uri->segment(segment_no)`. where `segment_no` is the position of the parameter in the uri. for example position of `joe` is 2.

Comment: My doubt is not about how to access the parameters but about 'How to set up the form to call a uri string based url'

Comment: You cant set up a form like this. What i can think of right now is you can manually make the desired url by appending the values from different text fields using javascript and then go to that url using window.location.href